# For every $w\ne0$, on every small disc $B=B(0,\epsilon)$, there is some $z$ in $B$ with $e^{1/z}=w$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Let $w$ be a nonzero number in the set of complex numbers. 
Show that for $f(z)= e^{\frac{1}{z}}$, on every small disc $B= B(0,\epsilon)$, there is a $z$ in $B$ with $f(z)=w$.

I'm a bit stuck on how to approach this problem. Should I perhaps try to find the Laurent series of $f(z)$ and make some assumptions from there?

Comment: The Laurent series idea is a good start. From there, think about the classification of isolated singularities (removable, pole, essential) - what facts do you know about all three of these?

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer, Batman?

Comment: Earth to Batman, come in, please.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a branch of the logarithm function, then choose an integer $n$ such that $|\log w+2\pi in|>\epsilon^{-1}$. Let $z=(\log w+2\pi in)^{-1}$. Then $|z|<\epsilon$, and $e^{1/z}=w$, as requested.